# Is there a way to get the display tags back (with spaces), rather than the coded versions?

Tags: flickr, phpflickr

I'm using phpFlickr to make this query:

```
$photos = $f->photos_search(array(
  'tags'=>$tag,
  'sort'=>'date-taken-desc',
  'per_page'=>100,
  'user_id'=>'me',
  'privacy_filter'=>5,
  'extras'=>'date_taken,tags,url_sq,description'
));
```

It's working great, except, I have some tags with spaces in them and I want to display them that way. Is it possible? Maybe I need to do a tag lookup first?

Answer (score 1):

found it:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUserRaw.html